# data not saving to db, but no errors - laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5

I tried the following code, but the data was not getting saved to the DB , and no error showed up. It properly redirected to the `tags.index` page and the success message also displayed, except data getting saved to DB.

But simply changing the `$tags` to `$tag`, it started working and the data is getting saved to DB. Can someone explain what the problem was.

```
public function update(CreateTagRequest $request, Tags $tags)
    {
        //dd($request->name);
        $tags->update([
            'name' => $request->name
        ]);

        return redirect(route('tags.index'))->with('success','Tag Updated Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Give us your route declaration and your blade view, and we will be able to bring you an answer.

Comment: Should you note be using `Tag` instead of `Tags` as your `update()` method is updating a single tag?

Comment: The Tags is the Model, the issue is with the variable $tags. Does laravel differentiate singular plural words? After all shouldn't we be able name a variable what we like it to be. Or is it that, when binding the model and variable like in the code the variable should not be same as the Model name. Like in this case `Tag` model binding `$tags` variable.

Comment: @iArcadia `Route::resource('tags','TagsController');`

Comment: Missing your blade view, please edit your post.